# Hyperlink with navigationURL

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create a hyperlink with Mailto: Email address should be taken whant entered in a textbox. How do I do this?

Send Email

I want to bind Mail to to a text box value.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the aspx page, put:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the aspx.vb code-behind, do:

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" & TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I have been trying, if don't specify navigationurl ad design time my Hyperlink doesn't look like a hyperlink. I am using Visual studio 2010

Comment: Then put NavigateUrl="#" in the hyperlink declaration.

Comment: TextChanged is not firing up... in 2010. I installed it last week. No clue with this

Comment: Did you put AutoPostBack="True"?

Comment: thats a really bad idea to handle this on the textbox text_changed event, it's going to fire for every character you type in (once you get it to fire at all).  Better to either handle on submit or do some AJAX with a timer between keystrokes involved.

Comment: @David If user643062 is asking such a simple question, he probably is learning ASP.NET and not putting the code in production (hopefully). So performance is not a concern.